# Magento 1.6.1: What is options_container?

Tags: api, magento, e-commerce

When I use the Magento product.info API call to get the information of a specific product it always seem to give a field named '**options_container**' with a value '**container2**'.

What is it?

Don't see it in the GUI control panel when creating the product.

And here's some more fields that if someone could enlighten me about, that'd be great:

1. msrp_enabled
2. msrp_display_actual_price_type
3. msrp

I'm trying to create products via the product.create API call. As I don't know what these fields mean and they all have non-empty values by default (which I can't seem to be able to set in GUI), I don't know what would happen if I leave them blank when creating a product via the product.create API call - or what value I should use for them... Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the admin take a look at *Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes*, you should be able to see these attributes defined.

**options_container** is a section of layout where product options can be displayed. This depends entirely on the theme being used but typically "container1" is higher up the page, near the price. "container2" is further down, below the description and has more horizontal space to use.

**msrp** is "Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price". I'm unaware of it being used anywhere but again, individual themes can show it on the frontend at their discretion.

Answer (score 2):

options_container: GUI admin panel->product data page->Design tab->"Display Product Options In" (Magento CE 1.9.1)

The values are as clockworkgeek described them. In the newer edition they are called "Product Info Column" and "Block After Info Column"

msrp is Manufacturer Suggested Retail Price

msrp_enabled decides whether the price is hidden as in "Click to Display Price"

msrp_display_actual_price_type decides how the price of msrp_enabled is displayed, "In Cart", "Before Order Confirmation" or "On Gesture"

see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150501163518/http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/Resources/Products/products.html) and CTRL-F search for the field names.